# How to set delegate for case: Message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

When I login, I call the VC2 by segue from VC1

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"embeddedVC2"]) {
        self.VC2 = [segue destinationViewController];
        self.VC2.delegate = self;
    }
  }
```

and I have the dealloc in VC1

```
 -(void)dealloc{
   self.VC2.delegate=nil;
}
```

The delegate in VC2 is declared as (nonatomic,assign)

and in VC2, I'm performing a download operation, and when it finishes I'm calling

```
  [self.delegate downloadFinish:self.downloadData];
```

The problem is that by the time the download is finsihed, the dealloc in VC1 gets called , and its making the delegate in VC2 nil. So the delegate is nil, and  [self.delegate downloadFinish:self.downloadData]; doesnt work.

If I remove the `self.VC2.delegate=nil` in the VC1 `dealloc` method, then I get the exception
at the line:

```
   [self.delegate downloadFinish:self.downloadData];
```

*message sent to deallocated instance* : as VC1 is deallocated and I can't do anything on it.

What is the proper way of handling this scenario ?

**Note**: This only happens when I redo the procedure again.

**Case 1** : login -> VC1 ->VC2 works fine, delegate notifies me about the download finish

**Case 2** :**no dealloc method in VC1:**

login -> VC1 -> VC2 -> logout ->login -> VC1 -> VC2 (boom) crash-message sent to deallocated instance

**Case 3** :**with dealloc in VC1 and self.VC2.delegate=nil in it:**

login -> VC1 -> VC2 -> logout ->login -> VC1 -> VC2 nothing happens,as delegate is set to nil

I tried using Zombie instrument, but I didnt understand a bit. I was confused by the long stack trace and was lost looking at the reference count and retain count numbers. I can post the stacktract in the instruments if you need.

**Edit:**

I changed the delegate to `nonatomic` and `weak` and removed the `dealloc` methods.

and when I load `VC2` by segue , the VC2 delegate is not nil in `viewDidLoad`, but it turned to be `nil` by the point the download is finished, and at this point I'm still in VC2. I wonder what is making the delegate nil as I didn't move to another VC.

Comment: Delegate properties should be `weak`, not `assign`.

Comment: if I set it to weak, then still do I need to make delegate nil in dealloc method ?@rmaddy

Comment: No, there should be no need to set it `dealloc`. But it won't hurt if you do.

Comment: It solves one confusion for me (case 1&2), but the delegate is nil . I still have the question for case 3. The delegate is nil, even though I set it through segue. @rmaddy

Comment: the strange thing is in the viewDidLoad the delegate is not nil, but when the compiler reaches the point [self.delegate downLoadFinish: ......the delgate is nil.  I wonder what is making the delegate nil! @rmaddy

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Add a temporary setter for the `delegate` property and set a conditional breakpoint when `nil` is passed.  Look at the call stack and you will see what is resetting it.

Comment: thnx for the idea. I will try and update my question. @Droppy

Comment: It's a crude way of doing it; you can do it all in the debugger without adding temporary methods, but it might be a bit too fiddly...

Comment: When I write a setter method for delegate, it gets called infinite times and app gets crashed the exc_bad _access @Droppy

Comment: You should start a new question, including as much detail as possible (like the call stack etc.). This question has been answered by rmaddy.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you either push a VC, present a VC, or add as a childViewController, this way the parent doesn't get deallocated.  Otherwise if you are using tabbar for example, you need to make sure VC1 never gets set to nil.

I would rewrite the way you are adding VC's to your hierarchy if you are spending too much time trying to solve it.